# How to support multiple secondary mongodb instances in connection string

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have one mongodb replica set cross 2 data centers, the deployment architecture is similar like [Read Preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/), there are 3 instances in data center 1 and 2 instances in data center 2.

Now, i hope that applications in data center 2 can connect to the secondary instances as readonly replica set, for example, `mongodb://host1,host2:database?replicaSet=&readPreference=secondary` , but it always tried to connect mongodb instances in data center 1 (applications in data center 2 can't access mongodb in data center 1, and vice versa), in fact, i had disabled `useUnifiedTopology` . i can only use standalone mode in our applications in data center 2 now, but there are single point of failure risk.

Comment: I think the linked documentation in your post says that the data-center-2's clients connect with Read Preference [nearest](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#mongodb-readmode-nearest). That is how the reads from the data-center-2 are directed to that particular member.

Comment: The mongodb driver still try to connect the instance in data-center-1 after we changed the readPreference=nearest.

Comment: Finally, we setup one TCP layer LB in front of mongodb instances to resolve this issue.